# How to add page numbers back in moderncv

Tags: page-numbering, moderncv

I'm trying to create a CV using Overleaf with Tex Live 2014 and `moderncv`. How can I add page numbers to my document? Looking at a template, it appears you can only add page numbers if the you include `\makelettertitle`and `\makeletterclosing`, but this ruins the formatting of my document.

Comment: It seems to me that the page number only appears if you have multiple pages, and the appearance is not related to `\makelettertitle`. Maybe your test case is too small for the page numbers to appear. Also note that you need to compile TWICE.

Comment: @domperor I added enough text to make the document four pages, and compiled twice, but there are still no page numbers unfortunately.

Comment: @domperor Do you happen to have a MWE in Overleaf (2014) where the page numbers are shown?

Comment: I have been trying w/ the 2012 ver you gave me before & the 2017 ver I have. I have not tried with 2014. Okay, I will try w/ that version on Overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have tried with TeX Live 2014 ver. on Overleaf and found out the problem. The label `lastpage` is broken in that version. All u need to do is to manually set the `lastpage` label just before `\end{document}`, as follows:

```
\label{lastpage}\end{document}
```

Again, do not forget to compile twice.

Comment: Overleaf MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/cmhmdvmhmwqd

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!